# Relativist or not, if harm is objectively bad, is that sufficient for mind independent values?

Tags: metaethics, objectivity, relativism

I suspect that harm is *objectively bad*, but I'm unsure whether the negative value of what is harmful is mind independent, because while I cannot take seriously any claim that, relative to me or not, my being harmed is not a bad thing independent of what I think/feel/claim about it, I am unsure whether what counts as harm is also mind independent.

If harm is objectively bad, is that sufficient for mind independent values?

Comment: harm is "objectively" bad, at least for law.

Comment: What counts as harm is value-neutral, one can love or hate whatever it is defined as. So if you are unsure only about that then you are not unsure about its value, only about its content. And since you postulated its value as "objectively bad" then you have trivially postulated a mind independent value. The only way it would be insufficient is if "harm" turns out to be an illusory label that does not pick out anything cogent, which would make your postulation likewise. That seems unlikely, but since you are unsure what it is we can't really tell.

Comment: hmm interesting, and i think you may be right @Conifold can you quote anyone to support you from 3rd sentence?